# MySQL joining with PHP

Tags: mysql

Sometimes my eyes goes bonkers with these joins. Please help me build the select statement

product_version

```
 id    version
----------------
  1     apple
  2     orange
  3     pineapple
```

executions

```
 id    class       methods    plat_version    orig_prod_version
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1    SomeTest     check          2               1 
  2    AnotTest     submit         3               2
```

I want to pull from the executions but convert the numbers from the version that is in the other table. I was trying to start off and just do one at this point. Here is what I have

```
SELECT e.id, 
e.class, 
e.plat_version, 
pv.id, 
pv.version, 
pv.version AS plat_version FROM executions e JOIN product_versions pv ON pv.version = e.plat_version
```

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: 
I am hoping that it pulls the records from the executions table but instead of seeing numbers for plat_version and orig_prod_version, I want to see corresponding version fields from the other table

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Have you tried this? What was the result? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to get the version name for both version columns in the "executions" table at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking something like this:

```
SELECT 
e.id, 
e.class, 
pv_plat.version AS plat_version, 
pv_orig.version AS orig_prod_version,
FROM executions e 
JOIN product_versions pv_plat ON pv_plat.id= e.plat_version
JOIN product_versions pv_orig ON pv_orig.id= e.orig_prod_version
```

The idea is that you just join to the `product_versions` table twice, once for each id column that you have in the executions table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM executions e
LEFT JOIN product_version v
ON e.plat_version = v.id
LEFT JOIN product_version v2
ON e.orig_prod_version = v2.id
```

> [image]

**[SQL JOIN Explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**